# Convert text to numeric in R

Tags: r

I am new in R and I am trying to covert a column of my data frame which is text into numeric because I want to create scatterplot with class and values.

I am using the following command but is not working:

```
md$class = as.numeric(md$class)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share your dataset with us, e.g. by using `dput`.

Comment: may be it is `factor` so, `as.numeric(as.character(md$class))`

Comment: This is not enough information to really help. A common source of mistakes is that entries are often stored as factors. This can be checked with `class(md$class)`. In that case case `md$class <- as.numeric(as.character(md$class))` could help.

Comment: if i run the command class(md$class) said that is numeric, but when I try to create scatterplot - plot(t1,md$class), I get the following error message: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -In

Comment: In that case I rather suspect that `t1` is the troublemaker. Is that a numeric vector? It's really a pity that you didn't share a sample of the data. That would have made it much easier to help.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The OP stated that `class(md$class)` is not a factor.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you. After updating your question, you can ask for it to be reopened (cc @RHertel).

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Fair enough :-)